# Varying sqlldr peformance

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am using sqlldr to insert a 1 million rows into a table. I am using DIRECT=TRUE along with UNRECOVERABLE

A lot of the time I am getting extremely good performance time of under 10 seconds for the 1 million rows. But often I also get around 1 minute, making the range:

00:10 - 01:00

My question is regarding how performance can vary so much and which results to trust?

I was hypothesising that the good performance times are when Oracle has cached the data somehow, is this correct?

As this is a theory driven question I'm not posting the control file or sample data

Comment: Are there any other transactions to the same table running in parallel? It could be locking - direct locks entire table. So if there is any uncommitted changes to this table then it will wait. Do you delete rows before load from file?

Comment: No it is an unused test database. I'm testung using the TRUNCATE INTO schema.table_name

Comment: That's right. Then it might be something else...  Are there any indexes?

Comment: No indices or constraints, I was testing with basic tables that'd I'd created in a test schema. Should also note I'm running on an AWS RDS sitting in the US while I'm in the UK

Comment: So that could be network latency issue. but this is just kind of guess. I would try to do the same on local server. Are you uploading local file?

Comment: Yeah I was silly there - I'm running it from an AWS server in the same region so latency shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: My biggest concern is that the results were completely artificial as the rows were perhaps cached my Oracle. Have you any knowledge to inform re this?

Comment: I don't follow what you are thinking might be cached.  Oracle can't cache data that is not in Oracle.  Data being loaded by `SQL*Loader`, by definition, can't be cached by Oracle.  The file you are loading might be cached by the operating system, by the disk array's cache, it might have been moved to faster disk because it was being used heavily, etc.  But that's very speculative.  If you're concerned, you can get AWR reports/ monitor the operating system/ file system/ disk array to see where the performance delta is coming from.